# Flurry in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, flurry

Can I test the Flurry SDK in the iPhone simulator or should I test it in a device?
How many hours should I wait to see the statistics of my test code (the Flurry test) in my dashboard, or is this in real time? My problem is when I test I don't see anything in the dashboard (I have created an event and all events are created in the dashboard).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes Flurry SDK can be tested on the simulator and it takes time to display the statistics of application. If you will add any event over the click of any button then that Event name will be displayed within 30-40 mins. but it will display the description of those event after one day. I have tracked the page views which have been displayed after 2-3 days.
So i will suggest you to wait for a day.

Comment: Make sure you hit the Home button before Stopping the app in Xcode, your events may never be sent. [details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821996/flurry-events-not-showing-up-at-all/16777465#16777465)

Comment: What worked for me was relaunching the app in the simulator after I hit the "Home" button (Cmd-Shift-h).

Answer (score 2):

It's indicated in [FAQ](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ#Where.E2.80.99s_my_data.3F_How_often_is_data_updated_on_the_Flurry_portal.3F) section. It will take a couple of hours until your action on an application will generate reports in dashboard, but in the meantime in "Event Logs" will show that event is recorded properly and other metrics will be generated with regards to these data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Flurry SDK can be tested on the iPhone simulator. It takes time before you can see any events reported on the dashboard. I've observed the time varies. Sometimes the events are visible in the next 10 minutes sometimes they take longer.

Comment: i have tested Flurry, two hours ago and a have seen anything in my dashboard. i have given not the real name of my application when downloading the Flurry SDK. Do you think that's the problem ?

Comment: @izan, that's not the problem... just wait patiently :)