# How long does it take session data from a Flurry app to show up on the Flurry web site

Tags: iphone, flurry

I'm wondering how long it takes for data from a single Flurry session on a single device to show up on the Flurry web site.  Should it be instantaneous, several minutes, several hours, overnight?

Comment: Yet no one suggested a better forum in my other query.

Comment: And how does Flurry not relate to software development??

Comment: It's far from real time.  I only get new data about twice per day.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**EDIT (Feb 2015): please note this answer is almost 4 years old and provided info may not be accurate anymore.**

Well, it's not real-time and depends on the traffic to their servers. Basic events are shown in about 15 minutes, but sometimes between 30-45 minutes.

Similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472619/flurry-in-iphone-app).

If real-time is a must or you need other features, try this [7 Solutions for Tracking Mobile Analytics](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/articles/marketing/7-solutions-for-tracking-mobile-analytics/). It may be a bit outdated but mentions key providers like AdMob, Google Analytics, Bango, Localytics and Flurry.

Answer (score 2):

Ive found it varies... events take about an hour to show up but GPS locations usually show up over night.