# What does the basic step of Flurry do?

Tags: ios, flurry

Flurry includes the following in its [basic step](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted) for iOS.

```
1. Download the Flurry iOS SDK
2. Add the Flurry lib to your project
3. Incorporate the following two lines of Flurry code:

#import "Flurry.h"
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
     [Flurry startSession:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
     //your code
}
```

I have completed this step in my app and run the app on the simulator. But since [it takes time for updates to show on the dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472619/flurry-in-iphone-app), I'm not sure if this step is sufficient to track the simplest case of a user starting an application and then closing it. Is this basic step sufficient to monitor starting and closing of applications? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be enough.

However, be aware that Flurry tries to send batches of events. If you launch your app, Flurry won't immediately submit statistics. This can lead to some unexpected behaviour if you're developing and always restart your app from Xcode. This way, it might never get to the point where it actually submits the report. Flurry [writes in their documentation](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/Code/Doc):

> If testing on a simulator, please be sure to send App to background
>   via home button. Flurry depends on the iOS lifecycle to be complete
>   for full reporting.